# Mvc5 fileupload and read excel content

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to save and read from xls file using mvc5 and i got problem that saved file is not readable by excel... Can someone help me with this? Probly im missing something here.

```
public class ExcelFileUpload
{
    [DisplayName("Wybierz plik excela")]
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(ExcelFileUpload excel)
    {
        if (excel.File.FileName.Contains(".xls"))
        {
            var fileBytes = new byte[excel.File.ContentLength];
            var ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
            var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName());
            var path = Path.Combine(temp, file + ".xls");
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                ms.WriteTo(fs);
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                var ei = new ExcelImporter(path);
                ei.excel_getValue("A1");

            }
        }
        return View(excel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you able to open the uploaded Excel file manually, using Excel Office?

when not, then the problem appears during upload of the file, and it is not related to the Excel format.

when you can open the file with Excel, then the casue of problem schould be  in the ExcelImporter class.

It is easy to deal with new .xlsx file format, then you can make use of OpenXML SDK, 
see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx